# How to find out tags for all images required by certain kubernetes version?

Tags: kubernetes

I had some hard time in setup K8S using kubeadm method. Partially it was due to that the required docker image is not stored in my private registry. Yes I use a private registry in my office intranet rather than downloading them online.

For example, I have pause 3.2 and 3.5 in my registry. It used to work. However, my new work node has a different version of kubernetes SW suite (kubeadm, kubectl, kubelet, etc.) and it looked for pause 3.6, which I did not have. It caused some problem until I figured it out from the log and got the right one.

So my question is that, is there a way by checking my kubernetes SW version to tell the images version it expects? So that I can prepare them in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can list images with the following command:

`kubeadm config images list --kubernetes-version stable-1.23`